# Out of Range Runtime error when reading a vector of strings

Tags: c++, string, vector

I have written some code that has to find couples in a list of names.

> A couple always has the same exact prefix and the boy has the suffix
>   `"ka"` whereas the girl has the suffix `"ki"`.
>
> Eg: "bipinka" and "bipinki" are a couple.
>
> In the question, we are given `N` - the number of names - followed on
>   the next line by a list of strings separated by spaces.

My logic is that I will check the last two letters of each name. If it is `"ka"`, I add it to the `ka` vector after removing the last two letters and likewise for `"ki"`. Then I simply do an equality check and if equal, remove them from the vector since 3 `"bipinka"`s can't share 1 `"bipinki"` as their mate.

My code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#define sd(n) scanf("%d", &n)
#define slld(n) scanf("%lld", &n)
#define slf(n) scanf("%lf", &n)
#define pd(n) printf("%d\n", n)
#define plld(n) printf("%lld\n", n)
#define plf(n) printf("%lf\n", n)
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int N, i, j;
    string names[1001];
    vector<string> ka, ki;
    sd(N);
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        cin >> names[i];
        cout << names[i] << " "; //Entered this to check for error.
        string lastTwo = names[i].substr(names[i].size()-2);
        string name = names[i].substr(0, names[i].size()-2);
        if (lastTwo == "ka")
        {
            ka.push_back(name); 
        }
        else if (lastTwo == "ki")
        {
            ki.push_back(name);
        }
    }
    int ctr = 0;
    for(i=0; i<ka.size();i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<ki.size(); j++)
        {
            if(ka[i] == ki[j])
            {
                ka.erase(ka.begin() + i - 1);
                ki.erase(ki.begin() + j - 1);
                ctr++;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << ctr<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The problem lies somewhere in this segment:

```
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
{
    cin >> names[i];
    cout << names[i]; //Entered this to check for error.
    string lastTwo = names[i].substr(names[i].size()-2); //last two letters of name
    string name = names[i].substr(0, names[i].size()-2); //name without last two letters
    if (lastTwo == "ka")
    {
        ka.push_back(name); //Pushing in ka vector
    }
    else if (lastTwo == "ki")
    {
        ki.push_back(name); //Pushing in ki vector
    }
}
```

If the input given is:

```
6
bipinki bipinka bipinka bipinka betiki betika
```

My `cout` function only outputs:

```
bipinki bipinka bipinka bipinka betiki
```

And then the code encounters a `Run Time Error - Out of Range.`. I am using an online IDE so this is the error I see:
[image]

Comment: "_then the code encounters a `Run time error`_" What is the error?

Comment: Please see above. It does not tell in my IDE

Comment: Why don't you use an `unordered_set` to store your `ki` and `ka`. That will make sure you don't have duplicates in O(n) rather than having the nested loop like yours which will make it O(n^2)

Comment: First Step: `#include <string>`

Comment: @RandomGuy If there are 2 "Bipinka" and 2 "Bipinki", ans is 2.

Comment: @FirstStep Does not make a difference

Comment: your error is from these lines:                  `ka.erase(ka.begin() + i - 1);` and `ki.erase(ki.begin() + j - 1);1

Comment: @samadmontazeri Please explain.

Comment: let me see if I'm reading this right.  If `ki[0]` equals `ka[0]` you are going to erase `ki[-1]` and `ka[-1]`?

Comment: Ah yes, I will change that and check again

Comment: when `j` is zero, you are deleting a negative index! and that is a `Segmentation fault`

Comment: Indeed, that is thee error. thanks a lot. The second error is, once one is removed I must iterate again as size changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that you are erasing from the array **WHILE** you iterating it.

Since you can not debug on this online IDE (I recommend you download VS Community 2015). If you have a pen and a paper, write the values down and iterate them, then at half way, erase one element.

What is going to happen? Your loop will go out of range. This will happen because your loop's range is let's say `0 -> 5`, and **during** looping, one (or more) element was erased from your array. Now, your array is `0 -> 4` but your loop will tend to continue to reach the `-> 5`.. Surprise:

> Run Time Error - Out of Range.

Comment: Is it thus necessary for me to remove the element and loop again or should I simply replace the element with "" and if I find a "", I will skip it in my iterations.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad we were able to help :)

Comment: If you want to invalidate it on the rest of the iterations, just make the strings end in something other than 'ki' or 'ka'.  Append "XX" or something

Comment: @infixed I changed it to "" as that form of input was not allowed

Comment: Well if you mean empty string, just remember `""` could equal `""` at line 38.  so at minimum `ctr` will be wonky

Comment: @infixed I made it so that if string = "" then do not check line 38

Comment: FirstStep, I wanted to ask you something. Why did an error in my `remove` statement result in the last `cout` statement not printing?

Comment: @VaibhavBajaj Because this error causes the whole program to crash and not just your `remove`. Welcome to C++!